# Facebook Marketing API reach/delivery estimate with budget and time range

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-business-sdk

I'm making a small tool where my users can place ads on Facebook. Campaign, adset and ad creation is working fine, but i want to show users a small insight what they get for the budget they entered. I've tried `getDeliveryEstimate` and `getReachEstimate` as per described on [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/delivery_estimate/) and other Facebook developers guides, Stackoverflow  but none of these endpoints accepts budget and time range.

Is there any endpoint where i can pass budget and time range in order to calculate estimate based also on these variables?
In Ads manager in case if i change budget or time range, estimation changes instantly.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @K-Atilla, did you find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.